# First PHP college assignment - Passing parameters using hidden values?

Tags: php

I've been working on this PHP assignment for days and can't get past the wall I've hit. The first page has a "calculate" button and the calculated numbers are displayed on the same page. I think I have that working correctly.  The first page also has a "confirm" button that is suppose to take the user to the second page and display only some of the information from the first page.  I can't get the calculated numbers to transfer to the second page.

I contacted my professor for advice and he responded that the "validation and calculations happen in a postback and the confirmation will postback then send the user to the other page. When you transfer the data to the other page you will have to manually create the get or add the values as hidden values in the form" ...

I honestly don't know what he means. We haven't even covered hidden values. I did find many examples here and have tried without success.

Here is the code for my first and second page.

```html
<?php
// get the data from the form
$sales_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'sales_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$discount_percent = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'discount_percent',FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$total_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'total_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

// validate sales_price
if ($sales_price === FALSE) {
    $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be a valid amount';
} else if ($sales_price < 1.0) {
    $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be greater than 0';
} else {
    $sales_priceError = '';
}

// validate discount_percent
if ($discount_percent === FALSE) {
    $discount_percentError = 'Discount percent must be a valid amount';
} else if ($discount_percent < 1.0) {
    $discount_percentError = 'Discount percent must be greater than 0';
} else {
    $discount_percentError = '';
}


// calculate the discount and the discounted price
$discount_amount = $sales_price * $discount_percent / 100;
$total_price = $sales_price - $discount_amount;


?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Quote</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Price quotation</h1>
    <form id="priceForm" name="priceForm" method="post" action=''>
        <label for="sales_price">Sales price </label>
        <input type="text" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" required
               value="<?php echo $sales_price; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($sales_priceError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $sales_priceError; ?>
                </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="discount_percent">Discount percent </label>
        <input type="text" id="discount_percent" name="discount_percent" required
               value="<?php echo $discount_percent; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($discount_percentError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $discount_percentError; ?>
                </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p>Discount amount <?php echo '$' . number_format($discount_amount, 2); ?></p>
        <p>Total price <?php echo '$' . number_format($total_price, 2); ?></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Calculate"/>
    </form>
    <form id="confirmForm" name="confirmForm" method="post" action="confirm.php">
        <input type="hidden" id="sales_price" name="sales_price"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="discount_percent" name="discount_percent"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="discount_amount" name="discount_amount"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="total_price" name="total_price"/>
        <input type="submit" name="confirmSubmit" id="confirmSubmit" value="Confirm"/>
    </form>

    <p>Enter price and discount amount and click Calculate</p>
</section>
</body>
</html>



AND MY SECOND PAGE  ...  


<?php
$sales_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sales_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$discount_amount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'discount_amount', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$discount_percent = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'discount_percent', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$total_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'total_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);


// validate name
if ($name === '') {
    $nameError = 'Name is required';
} else {
    $nameError = '';
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Quotation confirmation</h1>
    <p>Sales price $<?php echo number_format($sales_price, 2); ?></p>
    <p>Discount amount $<?php echo number_format($discount_amount, 2); ?></p>
    <p>Total price $<?php echo number_format($total_price, 2); ?> </p>

    <h2> Send confirmation to</h2>
    <form id="nameForm" name="nameForm" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
               value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($nameError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $nameError; ?>
                </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required/>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="quoteSubmit" id="quoteSubmit" value="Send Quotation"/>
    <form id="returnForm" name="returnForm" action="index.php">
        <input type="Submit" name="returnSubmit" id="returnSubmit" value="Return"/>
    </form>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your input type, you have not given any **value** to input type that's why no value is pass to next page . 
Try doing something like this for all your hidden input  :

```
<input type="hidden" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" value="<?php echo $sales_price ?> "/>
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.

**Hidden Method**

Hidden inputs need to be passed a value otherwise they will return blank - eg:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" value="<?php echo $sales_price;?>"/>
```

You will then be able to access them in `confirm.php` like any other variable `$_POST['sales_price'];`

**GET Method**

Your other option would be to use get variables and asign them to your form action: eg:

```
<form id="confirmForm" name="confirmForm" method="post" action="confirm.php?sales_price=<?php echo $sales_price;?>&discount_amount=<?php echo $discount_amount;?>">
```

These can then be accessed through `confirm.php` like:

```
$_GET['sales_price'];
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have broken through the wall and now moving forward!

Comment: No problem, once you work out the logic it all becomes easier.